# O365 login is not working after log out in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365

There is some problem in my code not sure where I am getting wrong. Earlier same code used to work properly. Now I am trying to log in to application in both the ways i.e through ClaimPrincipal and Claim Identity. In both the ways Sometime data is null. Not sure where is the issue.
Below is my code

**StartUp.cs**

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    //PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );
```

**SignIn Method**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public void SignIn(string ReturnUrl = "/", string loginType = "")
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Account/Office365LoginCallback" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

**RedirectURL Code**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ExceptionHandler]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Office365LoginCallback(string code)
    {
        var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
        string userName = userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;
        string userEmail = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
        string userId = userClaims?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        ViewBag.TenantId = userClaims?.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;
  return Redirect("~/");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      throw ex;
 }
}
```

**SignOut Method**

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            //HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            //HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            //HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.UserEmail] = null;
            //HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.UserUpload] = null;
            //HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.UserImage] = null;
            //HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.CurrentRole] = null;
            //HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.Users] = null;
            //Session.Clear();
            //Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
```

Any Help will be appreciated. FYI I have tried same code in new project there is working fine but here in my old application its not working once clicked on Logout